# Name of security from open trades

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

In Pine scripting, is there a way to get the name of the security from the open trade?

I am iterating through a list of stocks to check conditions and take trade accordingly. After taking a trade, for next iteration I need to make sure the particular stock is not already in open trade.

I was thinking of writing the security name into the 'comment' of `strategy.entry` while taking trade and retrieving it through `strategy.opentrades.entry_comment`, but I am not sure how to use this as `strategy.opentrades` needs `tradenum` which I am not sure how to determine.
Is there any other way of getting the security name?

Comment: There is not possible in one strategy script to trade several securities simultaneously. Or do you mean some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

The **tradenum** can be found by using [strategy.opentrades](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dopentrades) -> returns int , so now you have the total number of open trades.

Next, you can use [strategy.opentrades.entry_id](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dopentrades%7Bdot%7Dentry_id)-> returns string, to get the id for every single one of those open trades.

Otherwise try, [syminfo.ticker](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_syminfo%7Bdot%7Dticker) to get the string of current symbol.